# PHP Generate PDFS from one template

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

I need to generate thousands of PDF files but they are very similar (only changing some info like name, order number, etc.). Currently I'm using HTML2PDF **for each document**. It takes **about 2 seconds to render and generate each PDF** file which I believe that can be decreased.
Can anyone recomend me a way to generate the pdf only once (as a template) and then replace the variables for each document?

That would turn things way faster!
Many thanks!

Comment: go with [`tcpdf`](http://www.tcpdf.org) or [`mpdf`](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

I am using this third party tool Try [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: Can you point me some documentation for templatings ? The documentation on the website always re-renders the html for each pdf

Comment: this might help http://www.adcworks.com/2007/10/wrapping-text-in-fpdf-table-cells/